# fontspec \setmainfont and fontspec prevents compiling after MiKTeX packages update

Tags: miktex, fontspec, miktex-update

I updated every package with MiKTeX console today (Dec. 7, 2021), and now I have issues compiling with XeLaTeX any document that uses `\setmainfont` or `\fontspec`, but loading the `fontspec` package works fine. Sometimes they work, but usually not, and I have not been able to determine under which condition they work. Deleting the auxilary files doesn't change anything; I thought I could produce a pdf when not using synctex as a command option but it seems not to always work either. I tried reinstalling `fontspec` already. Trying to compile the .tex file, it leaves me with a either empty or incomplete .log file, and a .synctex(busy) file. It tends to crash after reaching `fontspec.cfg`.

Here's is a MWE of what is causing me issues:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}
Hello World!

\fontspec{Consolas}
Try this thing?

\IfFontExistsTF{Latin Modern Roman}{T}{F}

\IfFontExistsTF{Times New Roman}{T}{F}

\IfFontExistsTF{Consolas}{T}{F}

\end{document}
```

At some point it worked when commenting out `\setmainfont` but now it doesn't unless also commenting out `\fontspec`. The pdf produced still contains "T" for the three `\IfFontExistsTF`.

Sorry if there are details missing but I really don't know what more to look for and that is the best I could troobleshoot it. I could send a list of the packages that were updated if that could be helpful.

Comment: (1) Do you get any errors? Can you provide a log file (update your question with it). (2) Does your miktex console have two modes? (miktex user and miktex admin) did you update in both?

Comment: you are not alone. It crashes for me too.

Comment: lualatex works fine, and loading fonts by file name too. It crashes for xelatex + font names. I opened an issue here https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/984

Comment: No crash with my TeX Live.

Comment: Similar issue happens when trying to use Arabic language in XeLaTeX

https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a due to bug in the miktex xetex binary. It has been reported here

https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/984

As a work-around use lualatex.